# Mount usb device, "name or service unknown"

Tags: linux, mount, usb

I am running Debian and I am trying to run an App on my smartwatch through Eclipse. It is not running with no real log reported. My current thoughts are that it is related to not really having a proper mount (I can be wrong).

When I plug in my smartwatch through USB, there appears a link on the desktop and I can freely use the GUI to move through the smartwatch. The link, or filesystem itself, is not found on the Desktop. The path of the smartwatch is: `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C004%5D/`.

Trying to find the connected device using `lsusb`, I am getting the device listed as: `Bus 003 Device 004: ID 091e:4c99 <..device..>`.

```
ls -al /dev/bus/usb/003/004
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 189, 259 apr 23 13:37 /dev/bus/usb/003/004
```

Trying to find the connected device using `fdisk -l`, I am getting a list of all the `/dev/loopX` and the `/dev/sda && /dev/sda1`. Nothing else shows.

With this, my train of thought was that maybe it wasn't mounted well enough.

So I tried that.

```
sudo mount /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C004%5D/ /media/usb-drive/
mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp: Name or service not known
```

Turns out that:

```
sudo mount /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C004%5D/
mount: /run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C004%5D/: can't find in /etc/fstab.
```

Am I on the right track, trying to mount it (proper), if so how to proceed? Or could there be something else not related to how the smartwatch is connected?

Comment: The `mtp:` statement in your mount line indicates that the device is connected in [MTP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Media_Transfer_Protocol) mode and not simply as USB storage device. You will need a tool like `mtpfs` to access it in the "classical" file-system-like fashion.

Comment: @AdminBee , thanks. It had put me into the right direction and I did learn a lot. However, for some reason my Vivoactive still has trouble syncing. Tried it this morning even on a Mac which also gave me problems. But this was definitely useful information.

Comment: You're welcome. If you can pin down the symptoms a little further, it might be worth opening a new question (as long as the problem is likely to have a solution using Linux/Unix tools, of course;) )